# Nexus OSS Yum: generate meta data 'option --no-database not recognized'

Tags: nexus, rhel5

I am using Nexus Repository Manager OSS 2.14.4-03 on RHEL5.

When using the Yum: Generate Meta Data capability, the task fails with the Nexus log saying:
'org.sonatype.nexus.yum.internal.task.CommandLineExecutor - Options Error: option --no-database not recognized.'

I know that RHEL5 only supports createrepo v0.4.9, which does not recognize the --no-database option.  This thread, however, https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-6801 raises the issue and claims it has been solved.  According to the comments on this thread, It seems there is a variable within the yum plugin called final @Named("${nexus.yum.useNoDatabaseSwitch:-true}") boolean useNoDatabaseSwitch)  .

but I can't figure out how to set this variable.  I think all I need to do is set this boolean to false.

Also, the plugin configuration mentioned in that thread might be outdated because the Yum plugin is now included with Nexus.  I can't seem to find any configuration options for the Yum plugin, no yum.xml to be seen.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Full nexus log from the Yum: Generate Metadata task is included below

> 2017-05-09 16:18:23,812-0700 INFO  [pxpool-1-thread-12] scitegicuser
>   org.sonatype.nexus.yum.internal.task.GenerateMetadataTask - Scheduled
>   task (Generate Biovia rpm yum metadata) started :: Generate Yum
>   metadata of repository 'biovia-rpms' 2017-05-09 16:18:24,069-0700
>   ERROR [pxpool-1-thread-12] scitegicuser
>   org.sonatype.nexus.yum.internal.task.CommandLineExecutor - Options
>   Error: option --no-database not recognized.
>
> 2017-05-09 16:18:24,072-0700 WARN  [pxpool-1-thread-12] scitegicuser
>   org.sonatype.nexus.yum.internal.task.GenerateMetadataTask - Yum
>   metadata generation failed org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException:
>   Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)   at
>   org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:377)
>   ~[nexus-yum-repository-plugin-2.14.4-03/:na]  at
>   org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:160)
>   ~[nexus-yum-repository-plugin-2.14.4-03/:na]  at
>   org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:147)
>   ~[nexus-yum-repository-plugin-2.14.4-03/:na]  at
>   org.sonatype.nexus.yum.internal.task.CommandLineExecutor.exec(CommandLineExecutor.java:68)
>   ~[nexus-yum-repository-plugin-2.14.4-03/:na]  at
>   org.sonatype.nexus.yum.internal.task.CommandLineExecutor.exec(CommandLineExecutor.java:43)
>   ~[nexus-yum-repository-plugin-2.14.4-03/:na]  at
>   org.sonatype.nexus.yum.internal.task.GenerateMetadataTask.doRun(GenerateMetadataTask.java:162)
>   [nexus-yum-repository-plugin-2.14.4-03/:na]   at
>   org.sonatype.nexus.yum.internal.task.GenerateMetadataTask.doRun(GenerateMetadataTask.java:69)
>   [nexus-yum-repository-plugin-2.14.4-03/:na]   at
>   org.sonatype.nexus.scheduling.AbstractNexusTask.call(AbstractNexusTask.java:163)
>   [nexus-core-2.14.4-03.jar:2.14.4-03]  at
>   org.sonatype.scheduling.DefaultScheduledTask.call(DefaultScheduledTask.java:418)
>   [nexus-scheduler-2.14.4-03.jar:2.14.4-03]     at
>   org.sonatype.nexus.threads.MDCAwareCallable.call(MDCAwareCallable.java:44)
>   [nexus-core-2.14.4-03.jar:2.14.4-03]  at
>   org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
>   [shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]  at
>   org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
>   [shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   [na:1.8.0_101]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>   [na:1.8.0_101]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>   [na:1.8.0_101]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [na:1.8.0_101]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [na:1.8.0_101]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   [na:1.8.0_101] 2017-05-09 16:18:24,073-0700 WARN  [pxpool-1-thread-12]
>   scitegicuser org.sonatype.nexus.yum.internal.task.GenerateMetadataTask
>   - Scheduled task (Generate Biovia rpm yum metadata) failed :: Generate Yum metadata of repository 'biovia-rpms' (started
>   2017-05-09T16:18:23-07:00, runtime 0:00:00.260) java.io.IOException:
>   Yum metadata generation failed    at
>   org.sonatype.nexus.yum.internal.task.GenerateMetadataTask.doRun(GenerateMetadataTask.java:166)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.sonatype.nexus.yum.internal.task.GenerateMetadataTask.doRun(GenerateMetadataTask.java:69)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.sonatype.nexus.scheduling.AbstractNexusTask.call(AbstractNexusTask.java:163)
>   ~[nexus-core-2.14.4-03.jar:2.14.4-03]     at
>   org.sonatype.scheduling.DefaultScheduledTask.call(DefaultScheduledTask.java:418)
>   [nexus-scheduler-2.14.4-03.jar:2.14.4-03]     at
>   org.sonatype.nexus.threads.MDCAwareCallable.call(MDCAwareCallable.java:44)
>   [nexus-core-2.14.4-03.jar:2.14.4-03]  at
>   org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
>   [shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]  at
>   org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
>   [shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   [na:1.8.0_101]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>   [na:1.8.0_101]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>   [na:1.8.0_101]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [na:1.8.0_101]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [na:1.8.0_101]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   [na:1.8.0_101] Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException:
>   Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)   at
>   org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:377)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:160)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:147)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.sonatype.nexus.yum.internal.task.CommandLineExecutor.exec(CommandLineExecutor.java:68)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.sonatype.nexus.yum.internal.task.CommandLineExecutor.exec(CommandLineExecutor.java:43)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.sonatype.nexus.yum.internal.task.GenerateMetadataTask.doRun(GenerateMetadataTask.java:162)
>   ~[na:na]  ... 12 common frames omitted 2017-05-09 16:18:24,407-0700
>   WARN  [pxpool-1-thread-12] scitegicuser
>   org.sonatype.scheduling.DefaultScheduledTask - Exception in call
>   method of scheduled task Generate Biovia rpm yum metadata
>   java.io.IOException: Yum metadata generation failed   at
>   org.sonatype.nexus.yum.internal.task.GenerateMetadataTask.doRun(GenerateMetadataTask.java:166)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.sonatype.nexus.yum.internal.task.GenerateMetadataTask.doRun(GenerateMetadataTask.java:69)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.sonatype.nexus.scheduling.AbstractNexusTask.call(AbstractNexusTask.java:163)
>   ~[nexus-core-2.14.4-03.jar:2.14.4-03]     at
>   org.sonatype.scheduling.DefaultScheduledTask.call(DefaultScheduledTask.java:418)
>   ~[nexus-scheduler-2.14.4-03.jar:2.14.4-03]    at
>   org.sonatype.nexus.threads.MDCAwareCallable.call(MDCAwareCallable.java:44)
>   [nexus-core-2.14.4-03.jar:2.14.4-03]  at
>   org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
>   [shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]  at
>   org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
>   [shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   [na:1.8.0_101]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>   [na:1.8.0_101]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>   [na:1.8.0_101]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [na:1.8.0_101]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [na:1.8.0_101]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   [na:1.8.0_101] Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException:
>   Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)   at
>   org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:377)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:160)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:147)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.sonatype.nexus.yum.internal.task.CommandLineExecutor.exec(CommandLineExecutor.java:68)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.sonatype.nexus.yum.internal.task.CommandLineExecutor.exec(CommandLineExecutor.java:43)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.sonatype.nexus.yum.internal.task.GenerateMetadataTask.doRun(GenerateMetadataTask.java:162)
>   ~[na:na]  ... 12 common frames omitted

Answer (score 0):

Yum support in Nexus requires RHEL6 or higher, it won't work with the createrepo in RHEl5.